# ¿Como mantener la sincronía de dos tablas temporales, al salvarlas con nuevos id´s?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas, podríamos decir que temporales, por que se usan como un mecanismo previo al salvar un conjunto de datos mayor. Los datos de ambas tablas están relacionados por un campo `id` pero ocurre que en un determinado momento hay que salvar los datos de una de ellas en la tabla física definitiva y en ese momento debemos recalcular dicho `Id` o peor aún, podría ser que el campo sea un IDENTITY.

El problema lo tengo luego cuando debo salvar la segunda tabla a su tabla definitiva,  no puedo salvar el `id` original, debiéramos salvar el definitivo que ya le hemos generado en la primer tabla, de modo de mantener la sincronía.

Mi idea era usar el `OUTPUT INSERTED` para registrar el nuevo `id` al insertar en la primer tabla, pero necesitaría quedarme de alguna forma con el `id` original para luego mediante un `JOIN` poder insertar en la segunda 
tabla y darle a los registros de ésta, el nuevo `id`. Lamentablemente, entiendo que en un `OUTPUT INSERTED` no puedo quedarme con datos que no vayan a ser insertados. Tampoco se me ocurre otro mecanismos para resolver esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950418/6836377) me ayudó a entender de que forma solucionar el problema usando la clausula `OUTPUT INSERTED` junto con `MERGE INTO`, supongamos que tenemos una tabla temporal `@Desde` con estos datos:

```
Id  Dato
--- -----
11  Dato1
22  Dato2
```

El `id` es temporal y como ya digímos está en sincronía con los datos de otra tabla temporal que  a los efectos de esta prueba de concepto no hace falta definir. Cuando salve definitivamente los datos en una tabla como la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Detalle TABLE (
    Id      INT IDENTITY,
    Dato    VARCHAR(255)
)
```

No vamos a salvar el `id` temporal, no lo necesitamos salvar, sin embargo si nos interesa para poder recomponer el mismo cuando salvemos definitivamente la segunda tabla. La idea es que mediante una clausula `OUTPUT INSERTED`, podamos quedarnos con el nuevo `id` y con el `id` original. Esto mismo lo podemos hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @Detalle TABLE (
    Id      INT IDENTITY,
    Dato    VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @Desde TABLE(
    Id          INT,
    Dato        VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @Insertados TABLE(
    Id          INT,
    IdOriginal  INT,
    Dato        VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @Desde (Id, Dato)
VALUES  (11, 'Dato1'),
    (22, 'Dato2')

MERGE INTO @Detalle R USING @Desde D ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Dato)
    VALUES (D.Dato)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Dato, D.Id
    INTO @Insertados (Id, Dato, IdOriginal);

SELECT  *
    FROM @Detalle

SELECT  *
    FROM @Insertados
```

En `@Detalle` (nuestra tabla definitiva), tenemos los datos con los nuevos `id`´s:

```
Id  Dato
--- -----
1   Dato1
2   Dato2
```

Y en `@Inserted` tenderemos la relación entre nuevos y viejos `id`´s lo que nos va a permitir luego, salvar correctamente la segunda tabla que mencionábamos:

```
Id  IdOriginal Dato
--- ---------- -----
1   11         Dato1
2   22         Dato2
```

**Importante**: Esta solución entiendo que es válida únicamente a partir de SQL 2008 por lo del `MERGE`, sería interesante encontrar una alternativa más amplia en el tiempo, pero al menos está solución me resulto práctica.